# Использование Loguru с Aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Я пишу Telegram-бота с использованием Aiogram. Я бы хотел использовать Loguru для ведения логов бота, потому что библиотеку намного проще настраивать: хочу хранить логи за каждый день в отдельном файле и использовать автоочистку.

```
from sys import stderr

from loguru import logger

from aiogram.utils import executor

from bot import dp

from handlers import admin, client


logger.add(stderr, enqueue=True)

admin.register_handlers()
client.register_handlers()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Однако логи Aiogram не выводятся в консоль, как это происходит при настройки `logging`.

Возможно ли настроить Loguru для использования с Aiogram?

Answer (score 0):

Для aiogram 3.2 подошел такой подход:

```
import logging
from loguru import logger

class InterceptHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        level = logger.level(record.levelname).name
        logger.log(level, record.getMessage())


logging.getLogger('aiogram').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('aiogram').addHandler(InterceptHandler())
logging.getLogger('asyncio').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('asyncio').addHandler(InterceptHandler())
```